# Word Wrap in UIAlertController in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller

I am building a quiz app in swift 3 which leverages a UITableViewController to list the questions, and what I would like to use is a Alert View to post the question with a variety of answers to choose from.  I have it working the way I want it to with one giant quirk, and that is that the long answers get a much smaller font, and are truncated by swapping out text in the middle of the answer with an ellipsis.

How do I get the answers to word wrap in the AlertView actions, and maintain the same size font?  Note that manually inserting "\n" in the answers after a certain character length is not realistic because there are hundreds of questions in the question dictionary.

[image]

This is the code for the AlertView:

```
func showQuestion(questionNum: Int) {

        let alertTitle = "Question \(questionNum + 1)"
        let qDict = test[questionNum] as! [String:String]
        let alertMessage = qDict["Question"]

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // add the actions (buttons)
        if qDict["Option-A"] != "" {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: qDict["Option-A"], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        }

        if qDict["Option-B"] != "" {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: qDict["Option-B"], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        }

        if qDict["Option-C"] != "" {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: qDict["Option-C"], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        }

        if qDict["Option-D"] != "" {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: qDict["Option-D"], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        }

        if qDict["Option-E"] != "" {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: qDict["Option-E"], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Come back to this one", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I have added the code below the image. Thank you for looking at it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
  UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 0 // change your self what you need
```

for e.g

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                  message: "dsfdsf",
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "karthik tested for the word wrap text in alert",
                                     style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

      // number of lines
      UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 0
      // for font
      UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: That is an interesting idea. Where do I stick that line?  In the method I posted above?  Answering my own question: Yes, that's where it goes :)

Comment: Thank you!!!  At some point down the road I am going to try to change the font used, and also change the background of every other action... but not yet  :)

Comment: @zeeple - i think alert action is not possible , you can change the background of uialertcontroller only